# Overwriting boolean value in Phoenix/Elixir

Tags: phoenix-framework, elixir

I am working with the Elixir/Phoenix, and trying to overwrite default boolean, however it doesn't work. Here is my schema:

```
schema "orders" do
field :number_of_customers, :integer
field :completed, :boolean, default: false
belongs_to :table, Pos1.Table
has_many :order_items, Pos1.OrderItem
```

So on default the order value "completed" is false, however I want to make a button, onclick when the value changes to true. I decided to use hidden_input for overwriting, but for some reason, the value don't change when i click the button.

```
<%= form_for @completedchangeset, @action, fn f -> %>
<%= hidden_input f, :completed, value: true %>
<div class="form-group">
<%= submit "Order completed", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

All other value can be changed, however boolean cannot. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can't check right now but try to use 0 and 1 instead of false and true.

Comment: You mean to change type from boolean, and just use 0 and 1? Because, I believe boolean can accept only true/false [syntax](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html). Or there is a way around?

Comment: @Ilya are you sure you have `:completed` in either the required or the optional fields in the `Order` model?

Comment: @Dogbert Nope, i missed that. Just added, however the hidden_input didn't work, if i assigns "true" value. So, I modified <%= hidden_input f, :completed, value: 1 %> and now it works. Thank you!

Comment: So @SashaFonseca you were right! In my order model, I kept the boolean, only the hidden_input should have been 0 or 1. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, for some reason `value: true` is printing `value="value"`, which is not a valid value for a boolean field. `"true"` works, and so does `1`.

Comment: @Ilya nice no problem. I added the answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing a boolean value for `hidden_input` you need to use the values 0 or 1 instead of false and true (I believe this is because of HTML only dealing with 0 and 1).